# Android Refactoring - Best Practice - drawable shape and colors.xml

Tags: android, xml, design-patterns, resources, colors

This may sound stupid, but I can think of reasons for and against.

Should I refactor the two color's out my drawable/shape.xml gradient into colors.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:endColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke 
        android:width="3dp" 
        color="@color/transparent" />
    <corners 
        android:radius="13dp" />
    <padding 
        android:left="10dp" 
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" 
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Keeping it in drawable/shape.xml show's that it is one entity ( a button ) and allows it to stay safe in one place.
Moving it to colors.xml allows these color's to be shared with other resource perhaps if I was creating a theme or style? But then when looking at colors.xml how would I know they combine to make a gradient color?

Does anyone have an opinion, I hope I've added enough of my though process to spark some debate.

I tried looking at the [Source](https://github.com/underhilllabs/iosched/tree/master/res/drawable) for the IO Sched app: [linky](https://github.com/underhilllabs/iosched/tree/master/res/drawable) to see what Google Employee's did, but I can't find them creating any shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that in general you should extract color resources, but make sure to name them logically.

For example, if you have something like `accent_color_1` and `accent_color_1_darker`, one should assume there could be a color ramp between these two colors used in the app. It would make less sense, however, for you to color ramp from something like `accent_color_1` and `accent_color_2`.

At the end of the day, though, it's really just a matter of personal or team preference.

Comment: Thanks that clears it up. It's more in the naming convention. Just trying to get a nice name for a color without being to general or to specific. Will work on it!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer defining all the colors in the separate xml file.

Apart from being able to use them in other resources you can give each color a *name* that describes what is it used for. So when you look at your shape code you will be reading something that makes sense and not some arcane hexadecimal characters.

If you can ensure that you are going to use that specific color just in one place, I guess it's just a matter of taste.